# how to send event to the client after specified time in web socket(pusher) Laravel?

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher, phpwebsocket

I am beginner in Web Socket. i am building an online exam system. i already have timer coundown system.so while any student taking an exam, JavaScript sends an ajax request every second to the server, so when countdown < 0 then JavaScript reloads the page to stop exam.

but now i want to achieve this functionality with web socket.
how to broadcast an event to the clients when the specified time passed.i am using pusher with laravel.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to run the countdown on the client and just validate timings with the server?

Comment: This is too broad a question. The quick answer is, setting up a pusher is not a trivial task to do. I suggest you read though the [manual about broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting) in detail and make the best attempt to implement it yourself and ask more specific questions here.

Comment: thanks. i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your Exam model add `started_at` attribute. Then make function which will run every minute (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#introduction) and check if time is expired. If it is just send an event to client using Pusher and reload the browser